# Only matching index root of / react router v4

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4

No matter what I do it'll work when the path is "/", but nothing else.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/test" render={({match}) => match && <h1>Yo</h1>} />
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

Either one works when I make the path "/", but I can't get any other route to work and I receive the message "Cannot GET /test". I think the error may have something to do with my server or webpack since I can get the routes to work when using Create-react-app, but I'm pretty clueless.

I suspect I may be doing something wrong w/ my server-side code of

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('client'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

my directory structure is

```
client
   compiled
      bundle.js
   App.js
  index.html
  index.js
  results.jsx

server
  index.js
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

For anyone with this problem in the future I was able to figure it out by adding the following code to my server file.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: can you post your whole server file? i just got deep links working in my app, and it was an issue with express. the app.get('*') had to go last after declaring my statics. but once that was set, react-router was able to handle deep linking.

Comment: @worc Just did. As you see there's not much more to it.

Comment: @worc Your comment helped me figure it out. I was missing an app.get statement.